# Bootstrap 3 Success Button has blue text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I converted a site from Bootstrap 2.3.4 to Bootstrap 3.3.4 using Bootply's tool. There is one problem that's giving me fits. The success button has blue text. When hovered it changes the background to blue with white text. Here's the HTML code:

```
eMail: <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><a href="mailto:your eMail address">Your Name</a></button>
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the button like this:

```
eMail: <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="mailto:your eMail address">Your Name</a>
```